# Rails 4 - Simple include multiple JSON inside another JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following controller:

```
  # orders_controller.rb

  def update_quantity
    @product = Product.by_id(params[:product_id])
    @product_details = ProductDetail.availables.by_id(params[:product_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @product.to_json( { :include => [ :current_price, :product_details ] } ) }
    end
  end
```

I just want to return a JSON with product data, including them current price and products_details, but just the available details (Inventory).

The products and current_price are working good but If I use :product_details, rails includes ALL the details and I want the contained  inside @product_details variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand your question. If `product_details` doesn't work, try this:

```
def update_quantity
  @product = Product.by_id(params[:product_id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { 
      render :json => @product.to_json( 
        { 
          :include => [ :current_price ],
          :methods => [ :product_details ] 
        } 
      ) 
    }
  end
end
```

In your `Product` model add:

```
def product_details
  ProductDetail.availables.by_id(self.id)
end
```

If you want only some fields of `product_details`:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { 
    render :json => @product.to_json( 
      { 
        :include => [ 
          :current_price, 
          product_details: {
           only: [
              :field1, 
              :field2
            ]
          }
        ] 
      } 
    ) 
  }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a `product_details` method in your `Product` class that returns every `ProductDetail` record associated with your `@product`. Most probably it has to do with [ActiveRecord association methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) when creating associations between models. For example `has_many :product_details` creates a `Product#product_details` method so when you serialize a product instance, you serialize `product_details` as well.

You will have to create a method that returns a subset of the records based on your requirments. For example:

```
class Product
  has_many :product_details

  def available_product_details
    product_details.available
  end
end
```

Now you can update your controller to look like this:

```
OrdersController < ApplicationController
 def update_quantity
    @product = Product.by_id(params[:product_id])    
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        render json: @product.to_json(include: [:current_price, :available_product_details])
      end
    end
  end
end
```